# Silverlight + Web Application with WCF missing system.linq

Tags: silverlight, wcf, linq, assemblies, compiler-errors

I'm creating a little Silverlight LOB app. I created the app + web in Blend 4 and I've opened the solution in VS2010 to add the WCF service. When I do so, it shows an error on `using System.Linq;`. It says:

> The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'(are you missing an assembly reference?)

I had VS2010 create the WCF service and I've tried to re-add the reference in for .NET 4 System.Core.dll.

So newbie dev question... What did I do wrong :)

Comment: So does it work after you add the System.Core reference?  Where the error comes from? The Silverlight project or the web app? Is the reference missing in one of the 2 projects?  Have you thought creating your solution with VS2010 (I have actually never even thought of creating my project with blend :S)

Comment: Ensure that you have installed at least .Net Framework 3.5 and set a correct target framework in the properties of the project.

Comment: I'm probably going to recreate the project in VS2010 because I think that blend is the problem. The problem is in a class file that I created in the web app, just weird behavior. I'll update tomorrow on what happens when I recreate in VS. Just don't want to lose my work on the interface... that'll teach me :)

Comment: having the same problem , i can't figure out why i can't add a reference to system.linq using .Net 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the references if you DO see the System.Core.dll assembly.

If you do not see it, add it manually.
It should be in `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll` (or in `Program Files (x86)` if your OS is x64).

After recompiling it should then work.